# How to increase the request timeout

Tags: fastify

I have a route in my API using Fastify. It does some processing that can take up to 1 minute and 20 seconds. I can't get around that.

When making the request, it returns a 504 - gateway timeout. So I want to increase the default time. I tried using these options

```js
const server = fastify({http2: true, http2SessionTimeout: 90000});
```

(I found I had to set `http2:true` in order to set `http2SessionTimeout`)

However, this is giving me CORS issues like `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` and `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`.

I tried updating the fastify-cors options like

```js
server.register(fastifyCors, {
    origin: false
})
```

But that doesn't help. Could someone kindly guide me where I'm going wrong? I just want the request to wait a little longer.

The ideal solution would be to implement a queue however I need a quick working solution for now.